# Hover scale effect on img causes overflow of parent

Tags: html, css

On hover, the image should increase in scale, but should not overflow its parent `.b` which has `overflow: hidden`.

Currently, the bottom of the image is spilling outside the parent `.b` on hover.

[Here is the example in a fiddle with SCSS.](http://jsfiddle.net/sop2s1dk/2/)

Here is the example with compiled CSS. Hover over the image:

```css
.image {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
}
.image .w {
  display: table-cell;
}
.image .b {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.image.va .w {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.image img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transform: scale(1);
}
.image:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.15);
}
```

```html
<div class="image va">
  <div class="w">
    <div class="b">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What to do?

Comment: There is a css property in ur file which uses scale on hovering the image.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what is going wrong here?

Comment: `.b` element as container with same size(img), but then I hover, img changes `.b` height. `.b` have `overflow:hidden`;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The image is escaping the overflow of its container because the image is `display: inline` and  `vertical-align: baseline` by default.

#### There are two options

1. It appears there is no need for the image to remain the default `display: inline`, so make the img `display: block` to eliminate the overflow

   **or**
2. Change the `vertical-align` property of the image to either `top / middle / bottom`

#### Full Example - image is display: block

Compiled CSS - [also in the fiddle with SCSS](http://jsfiddle.net/cytgp5Le/)

```css
.image {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
}
.image .w {
  display: table-cell;
}
.image .b {
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.image.va .w {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.image img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  transform: scale(1);
  display: block;
}
.image:hover img {
  transform: scale(1.15);
}
```

```html
<div class="image va">
  <div class="w">
    <div class="b">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @dkdf - you could also use `vertical-align` and `top`, `middle`, or `bottom` if you did want the image to remain `display: inline`

Answer (score 0):

Try this may it helps you.

[**LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/THE_MukulKant/sop2s1dk/6/)

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;        
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: This is working, but `height:150px`. Image height is fixed now. I want universal solution for different images.